# (Cisco/Apple) 802.11r Handoffs Failing: 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req

Tags: cisco, ieee-802.11, cisco-wlc

I am trying to set up a wireless LAN using two Cisco 3602i APs on a Virtual WLC running software version 8.2.160.0. My goal is to have an iPhone 6s using Voice-over-WiFi be able to fast-roam between these two APs using 802.11r/802.11k/802.11v without dropping the voice call.

As far as I can tell, I have set everything up for this according to Cisco and Apple recommendations, but the handoffs continually fail. Running 'debug client <iphone-mac-address>' on the controller produces the following message when the handoff attempts fail:

Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req

Unfortunately, a Google search for "key cache look up failed" returns only one result - an un-annotated pastebin dump.

Here is the vWLC configuration for the WLAN in question, id '2', SSID 'phone-test-5g':

```
(Cisco Controller) >show wlan 2


WLAN Identifier.................................. 2
Profile Name..................................... phone-test-5g
Network Name (SSID).............................. phone-test-5g
Status........................................... Enabled
MAC Filtering.................................... Disabled
Broadcast SSID................................... Enabled
AAA Policy Override.............................. Disabled
Network Admission Control
Client Profiling Status
    Radius Profiling ............................ Disabled
     DHCP ....................................... Disabled
     HTTP ....................................... Disabled
    Local Profiling ............................. Disabled
     DHCP ....................................... Disabled
     HTTP ....................................... Disabled
  Radius-NAC State............................... Disabled
  SNMP-NAC State................................. Disabled
  Quarantine VLAN................................ 0
Maximum number of Associated Clients............. 0
Maximum number of Clients per AP Radio........... 200

--More-- or (q)uit
ATF Policy....................................... 0
Number of Active Clients......................... 0
Exclusionlist Timeout............................ 60 seconds
Session Timeout.................................. 1800 seconds
User Idle Timeout................................ Disabled
Sleep Client..................................... disable
Sleep Client Timeout............................. 720 minutes
User Idle Threshold.............................. 0 Bytes
NAS-identifier................................... none
CHD per WLAN..................................... Enabled
Webauth DHCP exclusion........................... Disabled
Interface........................................ management
Multicast Interface.............................. Not Configured
WLAN IPv4 ACL.................................... unconfigured
WLAN IPv6 ACL.................................... unconfigured
WLAN Layer2 ACL.................................. unconfigured
mDNS Status...................................... Disabled
mDNS Profile Name................................ unconfigured
DHCP Server...................................... Default
DHCP Address Assignment Required................. Disabled
Static IP client tunneling....................... Disabled
Tunnel Profile................................... Unconfigured
Quality of Service............................... Silver

--More-- or (q)uit
Per-SSID Rate Limits............................. Upstream      Downstream
Average Data Rate................................   0             0
Average Realtime Data Rate.......................   0             0
Burst Data Rate..................................   0             0
Burst Realtime Data Rate.........................   0             0
Per-Client Rate Limits........................... Upstream      Downstream
Average Data Rate................................   0             0
Average Realtime Data Rate.......................   0             0
Burst Data Rate..................................   0             0
Burst Realtime Data Rate.........................   0             0
Scan Defer Priority.............................. 4,5,6
Scan Defer Time.................................. 100 milliseconds
WMM.............................................. Allowed
WMM UAPSD Compliant Client Support............... Disabled
Media Stream Multicast-direct.................... Disabled
CCX - AironetIe Support.......................... Enabled
CCX - Gratuitous ProbeResponse (GPR)............. Disabled
CCX - Diagnostics Channel Capability............. Disabled
Dot11-Phone Mode (7920).......................... Disabled
Wired Protocol................................... 802.1P (Tag=0)
Passive Client Feature........................... Disabled
Peer-to-Peer Blocking Action..................... Disabled
Radio Policy..................................... 802.11a only

--More-- or (q)uit
DTIM period for 802.11a radio.................... 1
DTIM period for 802.11b radio.................... 1
Radius Servers
   Authentication................................ Disabled
   Accounting.................................... Disabled
   Dynamic Interface............................. Disabled
   Dynamic Interface Priority.................... wlan
Local EAP Authentication......................... Disabled
Radius NAI-Realm................................. Disabled
Mu-Mimo.......................................... Enabled
Security

   802.11 Authentication:........................ Open System
   FT Support.................................... Enabled
   Static WEP Keys............................... Disabled
   802.1X........................................ Disabled
   Wi-Fi Protected Access (WPA/WPA2)............. Enabled
      WPA (SSN IE)............................... Disabled
      WPA2 (RSN IE).............................. Enabled
         TKIP Cipher............................. Disabled
         AES Cipher.............................. Enabled
      OSEN IE.................................... Disabled
      Auth Key Management

--More-- or (q)uit
         802.1x.................................. Disabled
         PSK..................................... Disabled
         CCKM.................................... Disabled
         FT-1X(802.11r).......................... Disabled
         FT-PSK(802.11r)......................... Enabled
         PMF-1X(802.11w)......................... Disabled
         PMF-PSK(802.11w)........................ Disabled
         OSEN-1X................................. Disabled
      FT Reassociation Timeout................... 20
      FT Over-The-DS mode........................ Disabled
      GTK Randomization.......................... Disabled
      SKC Cache Support.......................... Disabled
      CCKM TSF Tolerance......................... 1000
   Wi-Fi Direct policy configured................ Disabled
   EAP-Passthrough............................... Disabled
   CKIP ......................................... Disabled
   Web Based Authentication...................... Disabled
   Web Authentication Timeout.................... 300
   Web-Passthrough............................... Disabled
   Mac-auth-server............................... 0.0.0.0
   Web-portal-server............................. 0.0.0.0
   Conditional Web Redirect...................... Disabled
   Splash-Page Web Redirect...................... Disabled

--More-- or (q)uit
   Auto Anchor................................... Disabled
   FlexConnect Local Switching................... Enabled
   FlexConnect Central Association............... Enabled
   flexconnect Central Dhcp Flag................. Disabled
   flexconnect nat-pat Flag...................... Disabled
   flexconnect Dns Override Flag................. Disabled
   flexconnect PPPoE pass-through................ Disabled
   flexconnect local-switching IP-source-guar.... Disabled
   FlexConnect Vlan based Central Switching ..... Disabled
   FlexConnect Local Authentication.............. Disabled
   FlexConnect Learn IP Address.................. Enabled
   Client MFP.................................... Optional
   PMF........................................... Disabled
   PMF Association Comeback Time................. 1
   PMF SA Query RetryTimeout..................... 200
   Tkip MIC Countermeasure Hold-down Timer....... 60
   Eap-params.................................... Disabled
Flex Avc Profile Name............................ None
Flow Monitor Name................................ None
Split Tunnel Configuration
    Split Tunnel................................. Disabled
Call Snooping.................................... Disabled
Roamed Call Re-Anchor Policy..................... Disabled

--More-- or (q)uit
SIP CAC Fail Send-486-Busy Policy................ Enabled
SIP CAC Fail Send Dis-Association Policy......... Disabled
KTS based CAC Policy............................. Disabled
Assisted Roaming Prediction Optimization......... Disabled
802.11k Neighbor List............................ Enabled
802.11k Neighbor List Dual Band.................. Disabled
802.11v Directed Multicast Service............... Disabled
802.11v BSS Max Idle Service..................... Enabled
802.11v BSS Transition Service................... Enabled
802.11v BSS Transition Disassoc Imminent......... Disabled
802.11v BSS Transition Disassoc Timer............ 200
802.11v BSS Transition OpRoam Disassoc Timer..... 40
DMS DB is empty
Band Select...................................... Disabled
Load Balancing................................... Disabled
Multicast Buffer................................. Disabled
Universal Ap Admin............................... Disabled

 Mobility Anchor List
 WLAN ID     IP Address            Status                             Priority
 -------     ---------------       ------                             --------

802.11u........................................ Disabled

--More-- or (q)uit

MSAP Services.................................. Disabled

Local Policy
----------------
Priority  Policy Name
--------  ---------------


(Cisco Controller) >
```

And here is the complete output of a 'debug client ' capturing a failed roam/handoff event:

```
(Cisco Controller) >*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.187: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Doing preauth for this client over the Air
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.187: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Doing local roaming for destination address 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.187: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Got 1 AKMs in RSNIE
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.187: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c RSNIE AKM matches with PMK cache entry :0x4
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.187: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Created a new preauth entry for AP:44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.189: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.189: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c apfMsDeleteByMscb Scheduling mobile for deletion with deleteReason 8, reasonCode 1

*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.189: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Scheduling deletion of Mobile Station:  (callerId: 30) in 1 seconds
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.190: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.190: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Warning, ignore the DELETE_MOBILE_PAYLOAD from AP: 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1. STA connecting AP: 68:99:cd:51:75:d0, slot 1
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.531: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Doing preauth for this client over the Air
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.531: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Doing local roaming for destination address 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.531: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Got 1 AKMs in RSNIE
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.531: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c RSNIE AKM matches with PMK cache entry :0x4
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.531: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Removing TGr reauth entry for AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.531: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Created a new preauth entry for AP:44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.533: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.533: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c ignore the mscb delete request,mscb is already marked for deletion and being deletedAP:44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1)
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.535: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.535: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Warning, ignore the DELETE_MOBILE_PAYLOAD from AP: 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1. STA connecting AP: 68:99:cd:51:75:d0, slot 1
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.875: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Doing preauth for this client over the Air
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.875: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Doing local roaming for destination address 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.875: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Got 1 AKMs in RSNIE
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.875: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c RSNIE AKM matches with PMK cache entry :0x4
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.875: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Removing TGr reauth entry for AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:21.875: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Created a new preauth entry for AP:44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.877: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.877: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c ignore the mscb delete request,mscb is already marked for deletion and being deletedAP:44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1)
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.878: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:21.878: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Warning, ignore the DELETE_MOBILE_PAYLOAD from AP: 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1. STA connecting AP: 68:99:cd:51:75:d0, slot 1
*osapiBsnTimer: Aug 13 00:50:22.107: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c apfMsExpireCallback (apf_ms.c:638) Expiring Mobile!
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.107: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c apfMsExpireMobileStation (apf_ms.c:7442) Changing state for mobile cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c on AP 68:99:cd:51:75:d0 from Associated to Disassociated

*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c apfSendDisAssocMsgDebug (apf_80211.c:3459) Changing state for mobile cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c on AP 68:99:cd:51:75:d0 from Disassociated to Disassociated

*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Sent Disassociate to mobile on AP 68:99:cd:51:75:d0-1 (reason 1, caller apf_ms.c:7538)
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Sent Deauthenticate to mobile on BSSID 68:99:cd:51:75:de slot 1(caller apf_ms.c:7540)
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Resetting MSCB PMK Cache Entry 0 for station cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Removing BSSID 68:99:cd:51:75:de from PMKID cache of station cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Setting active key cache index 0 ---> 8
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Deleting the PMK cache when de-authenticating the client.
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c DOT11R: Sending cache delete
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Removing PMK cache entry for station cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Removing TGr reauth entry on AP station 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c apfMsAssoStateDec
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.108: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c apfMsExpireMobileStation (apf_ms.c:7581) Changing state for mobile cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c on AP 68:99:cd:51:75:d0 from Disassociated to Idle

*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.109: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c pemApfDeleteMobileStation2: APF_MS_PEM_WAIT_L2_AUTH_COMPLETE = 0.
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.109: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c 10.1.0.13 START (0) Deleted mobile LWAPP rule on AP [68:99:cd:51:75:d0]
*apfReceiveTask: Aug 13 00:50:22.109: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Deleting mobile on AP 68:99:cd:51:75:d0(1)
*spamApTask1: Aug 13 00:50:22.119: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c apfUpdateDeleteAckInMscb (apf_api.c:50821) Expiring Mobile!
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:22.218: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:22.220: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:22.221: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:22.562: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:22.564: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:22.565: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:54.724: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:54.726: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:54.727: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:55.066: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:55.069: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:55.070: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:55.410: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:55.412: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:55.413: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:55.754: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:55.756: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:55.757: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:50:56.097: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:56.099: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:50:56.100: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:51:57.477: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:51:57.479: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:51:57.480: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:51:57.821: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:51:57.823: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:51:57.824: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:51:58.165: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:51:58.167: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:51:58.168: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:51:58.509: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:51:58.511: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:51:58.512: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
*apfMsConnTask_5: Aug 13 00:51:58.853: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c no PMK cache entry for this client. Can't do preauth.
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:51:58.855: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Association Failed on REAP AP BSSID 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:fe (slot 1), status 11 0 802.11r Key Cache look up failed in (re)-assoc req
*spamApTask0: Aug 13 00:51:58.857: cc:20:e8:7f:64:8c Received DELETE mobile, reason UNKNOWN, from AP 44:ad:d9:8e:8b:f0, slot 1 ...cleaning up mscb
```

I have tried a fairly wide variety of configurations but have not been able to get this to work using any combination of settings. If anyone has any suggestions, I will greatly appreciate hearing them.

Comment: I know this might sound strange but try WPA or even WEP (for testing purpose). They handle caching diffrently. I had a customer that had a roaming issue and it was the compatibility in the way it cached. Took those to WEP (non secure network) and voila. You don't want WEP but changing it may help the troubleshooting process.

Comment: Changing this to an answer

Comment: With all authentication/encryption turned off, the handoffs between the two APs do work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this before with other issues. Did you try just doing WPA and disable 11r? Or even wpa2 aes without 11r? The iPhone has that adaptive 11r. Or did you try anything else in the answer below? Try disabling 11r in ap and using OKC. Let the iPhone adaptive 11r work and see how that goes with wpa2 aes.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may try turning off 802.11r in the AP and make sure your IOS is 10 or higher in case it's conflicting. IOS 10 and up have adaptive 801.11r and do not need it turned on in the AP. Reference [link to Apple doc](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202628)...

Quote from Apple... 
802.11r

When your iOS device roams from one AP to another on the same network, 802.11r uses a feature called Fast Basic Service Set Transition (FT) to authenticate more quickly. FT works with both preshared key (PSK) and 802.1X authentication methods.

iOS 10 includes support for adaptive 802.11r on Cisco wireless networks. Adaptive 802.11r offers FT without the need to enable 802.11r on the configured Cisco wireless network.

If that doesn't work out you could look into this. It was used before 11r. OKC option... 
I may have overlooked it in the config but have you tried opportunistic key caching OKC as described in this doc  [link to extensive Cisco doc](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless-mobility/wireless-lan-wlan/116493-technote-technology-00.html#anc18) instead of PKC and is there a Validate PMKID option? I didn't see it but this may be beneficial.